# Recursive map function with linked list C

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list

Hello i am trying to make a map function that takes a linked list and takes each integer and multiplies it by itself, so from current list i expect 1, 4, 9, 16, 25. I have made the square function and assigned it to a variable and tried to pass the list X and the function through the map function, whats my mistake?

```
#include <stdio.h> /* printf */
#include<stdlib.h> /* free */

typedef struct node
{
  int value;
  struct node* next;
} node;

node SENTINEL = {0, 0};

node * make_node(int v, node * q)
{
  node* p = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
  p->value = v;
  p->next = q;
  return p;
}

int square(int x)
{   
    return x * x;
}

int map(node* X, int x)
{
    if (X == NULL)
    {
        printf("List is empty");
        return 0;
    }
    
    while (X != &SENTINEL)
    {
        x = sf(X->value);
        printf("%d,", x);
        X = X->next;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int (*sf)(int);
    node* X =   
        make_node(1,
            make_node(2,
                make_node(3,
                    make_node(4,
                        make_node(5, &SENTINEL)
                    )
                )
            )
        );
    sf = square;
    int x;

    x = map(X);

    free(X);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the point of the `x` parameter in `map`? It would make more sense to pass a pointer to the `square` function. (Also, you are not passing a parameter there so I don't see how this compiles)

Comment: `sf`, which is used in `map`, is not declared here.

Comment: dint you get any compile errors for this `x = map(X);` where as definition says `int map(node* X, int x)`

Comment: Your compiler should be [complaining a lot](https://godbolt.org/z/d19fnn) about this code. Why don't you read the errors carefully and fix them? I believe this should be closed because it needs much more focus than "it doesn't work".

Comment: Naming your variables `X` and `x` may be clear for you, but not for the rest of the world.

Comment: @wildplasser I know but i am limited to what my instructor wants me to name the variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be you overlooked some parts of your program you dont have to pass two parameters for your function `map`, but instead declare a local variable.

and your function pointer declaration `int (*sf)(int);` should be out side main in order for you to access in `map` function.

```
int map(node* X)//, int x)
{
    int x = 0;
    
    if (X == NULL)
    {
        printf("List is empty");
        return 0;
    }
    
    while (X != &SENTINEL)
    {
        x = sf(X->value);
        printf("%d,", x);
        X = X->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ... and tried to pass the list X and the function through the map function

Your function is defined as:

```
int map(node* X, int x)
```

so the function is **not** expecting a function pointer. It's expecting an `int`

Change the function to:

```
void map(node* X, int (*sf)(int))
{
    int x;
```

and call it like:

```
map(X, square);
```

BTW: `free(X)` will only free the first element in the list. You need to free each element in a loop.

BTW: Using a sentinel in a linked list is not common. Normally the next-pointer of the last element is just set to NULL.

Putting it together, it could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
  int value;
  struct node* next;
} node;

node * add_front(int v, node * q)
{
  node* p = malloc(sizeof *p);
  p->value = v;
  p->next = q;
  return p;
}

int square(int x)
{   
    return x * x;
}

void map(node* X, int (*sf)(int))
{
    while (X != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d,", sf(X->value));
        X = X->next;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    node* X = NULL;
    for (int i = 5; i > 0; --i)
    {
        X = add_front(i, X);
    }

    map(X, square);

    while(X != NULL)
    {
        node* t = X;
        X = X->next;
        free(t);
    }

    return 0;
}
```